# StackOverFlow Error when implementing MiniMax Algorithm on Java Connect 4 game

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to create connect 4 game using JavaFX.
When I try to implement the minimax algorithm, it gives giving stack overflow error.

[image]

When it comes the AI's turn it is invoking the `movePiece(-1)` . There are 6 Cols, and 5 Rows in the game. It is working fine after I send a random number between 0 - 5 fine, but the issue is on the minimax function.
Here is the code I am using on AI Player's class.

```
package lk.ijse.dep.service;
public class AiPlayer extends Player {

    private final Board board;

    public AiPlayer(Board board) {
        this.board = board;
    }

    @Override
    public void movePiece(int col) {
        col = minimax(5, true);

        board.updateMove(col, Piece.GREEN); //Placing the piece on the selected col.
        board.getBoardUI().update(col, false);

        Winner winner = board.findWinner();
        if (winner.getWinningPiece() == Piece.GREEN) {
            board.getBoardUI().notifyWinner(winner);
        }

        if (!board.existLegalMove()) {
            board.getBoardUI().notifyWinner(new Winner(Piece.EMPTY));
        }
    }

    private int minimax(int depth, boolean maximizingPlayer) {
        if(depth == 0 || !board.existLegalMove()) return 0;

        if (maximizingPlayer) {
            int maxEval = (int) Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
            for (int i = 0; i < this.board.NUM_OF_COLS; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
                int heuristicVal = minimax(depth + 1, false); //<< Getting StackOverFlow Error
                maxEval = Math.max(heuristicVal, maxEval);
            }
            return maxEval;
        } else {
            int minEval = (int) Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
            for (int i = 0; i < this.board.NUM_OF_COLS; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
                int heuristicVal = minimax(depth + 1, true); //<< Getting StackOverFlow Error
                minEval = Math.min(heuristicVal, minEval);
            }
            return minEval;
        }

    }
}
```

When the AI's turn came, it is automatically invoking the movePiece(-1); It is a illegal move, so need to modify before sending it to updateMove(int col, boolean isHuman);

Board's existLegalMove function;

```
public boolean existLegalMove() {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_COLS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < NUM_OF_ROWS; j++) {
                if (pieces[i][j].equals(Piece.EMPTY)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: How do you call `minimax`? You never call `movePiece`...

Comment: @user16320675 I tried by adding negative value to the the depth, now that stack error is not giving, but AI is not putting a piece on the board

Comment: @trincot, it is calling on the BoardController class, it automatically invoke after the player's move.

Comment: My comment about `movePiece`, is that it is never called during the minimax search. I am not saying it should, but you should at least move a piece. If you don't move a piece then it makes no sense to increase the depth.

Answer (score 0):

The only condition that might stop the recursive call is

```
board.existLegalMove()
```

but you never modify the board before recalling the minimax function, so the recursivity goes as deep as it can till the Stackoverflow.

**How to correct the Stackoverflow :**

When you call minmax(), you pass depth+1, it should be depth-1.

**Correct the algorithm**

You need to modify the board before calling the minimax. You will also need to revert it after the call before checking another move. I do not have the implementation of the Board, so you might need to change/create the **updateMove** and **revertMove** methods. There are some optimizations that can be done, but I hope this will help you to resolve your issue.

```
private int estimateHeuristicValue(boolean maximizingPlayer) {
    return 0;// or something more complicated
}

private int minimax(int depth, boolean maximizingPlayer) {
    if (!board.existLegalMove()) return 0;
    if(depth == 0) return estimateHeuristicValue(maximizingPlayer);

    if (maximizingPlayer) {
        int maxEval = (int) Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.board.NUM_OF_COLS; i++) {
            board.updateMove(i,Piece.GREEN);
            Winner winner = board.findWinner();
            if (winner.getWinningPiece() == Piece.GREEN) {
                maxEval = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // AI is winning, maximal value
            } else {
                //No winner, go deeper
                int heuristicVal = minimax(depth - 1, false); //<< Getting StackOverFlow Error
                maxEval = Math.max(heuristicVal, maxEval);
            }
            board.revertMove(i,Piece.GREEN);
        }
        return maxEval;
    } else {
        int minEval = (int) Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.board.NUM_OF_COLS; i++) {
            board.updateMove(i,Piece.RED);
            Winner winner = board.findWinner();
            if (winner.getWinningPiece() == Piece.RED) {
                minEval = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // AI lost, minimal value
            } else {
                //No winner, go deeper
                int heuristicVal = minimax(depth - 1, true); //<< Getting StackOverFlow Error
                minEval = Math.min(heuristicVal, minEval);
            }
            board.revertMove(i,Piece.RED);
        }
        return minEval;
    }

}
```

Comment: Here is the code on the board.

`public boolean existLegalMove() {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_COLS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < NUM_OF_ROWS; j++) {
                if (pieces[i][j].equals(Piece.EMPTY)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }`

Comment: Please edit your question, and add such information there.

Comment: Done, added to questions   @trincot

Comment: Thanks. Now how does this relate to this answer? The board is never modified before making the recursive call.

Comment: @trincot, It didn't resolved yet